# AccessViolationException using unmanaged C++ DLL

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm trying, for the first time, to use an unmanaged C++ DLL ("res_lib") in a C# application. I've used [cppsharp](https://github.com/mono/CppSharp) to generate the PInvoke code: for example, one of the functions/methods I'm trying to call is `get_system_snapshot`. From the `.h` file, this is defined as

```
SYS_INT SYS_ERR get_system_snapshot(SNAPSHOT_PARMS* snapshotp);
```

`SYS_INT` and `SYS_ERR` equate to a `int32_t`. `SNAPSHOT_PARMS` is

```
typedef struct SNAPSHOT_PARMS
{
    SYS_ULONG   size;
    SYS_UINT    count;
    SYS_CHAR    serial_no[600];
} SYS_PACK_DIRECTIVE SYS_SNAPSHOT_PARMS;
```

cppsharp has turned this into the following code snippets:

**DllImport**

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[DllImport("res_lib", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
                EntryPoint="get_system_snapshot")]       
   internal static extern int GetSystemSnapshot(IntPtr snapshotp);
```

**Object**

```
 public unsafe partial class SNAPSHOT_PARMS : IDisposable
    {
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 608)]
  public partial struct __Internal
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal uint size;

        [FieldOffset(4)]
        internal uint count;

        [FieldOffset(8)]
        internal fixed sbyte serial_no[600];

        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [DllImport("res_lib", CallingConvention = global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.ThisCall,
            EntryPoint="??0SNAPSHOT_PARMS@@QAE@ABU0@@Z")]
        internal static extern global::System.IntPtr cctor(global::System.IntPtr instance, global::System.IntPtr _0);
    }
}

 public SNAPSHOT_PARMS()
        {
             __Instance = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(global::res_lib.SNAPSHOT_PARMS.__Internal));         
            __ownsNativeInstance = true;
            NativeToManagedMap[__Instance] = this;
        }
```

**Main code**

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SNAPSHOT_PARMS p = new SNAPSHOT_PARMS();
            var result = res_lib.res_lib.GetSystemSnapshot(p);
        }

 public static unsafe int GetSystemSnapshot(global::res_lib.SNAPSHOT_PARMS snapshotp)
        {         
            var __arg0 = ReferenceEquals(snapshotp, null) ? global::System.IntPtr.Zero : snapshotp.__Instance;
            var __ret = __Internal.GetSystemSnapshot(out __arg0);
            return __ret;
        }
```

When calling the function, I get the infamous:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I've tried changing the `CallingConvention` from `StdCall` to `Cdecl`, introducing `[In]` and `[Out]` to the `DllImport` etc, but all to no avail. Can anyone see anything obviously wrong with the code - as may be apparent, this is all new to me, and perhaps I'm asking a bit much for cppsharp to generate code that won't need tweaked.

**EDIT** The original C++ documentation has an example, where the struct is initialised by

```
#define INIT_STRUCT(struct_p) { memset(struct_p, 0, sizeof(*(struct_p))); (struct_p)->size = sizeof(*(struct_p)); }
```

and is used

```
 SNAPSHOT_PARMS snapshot_parms;
 SYS_ERR result;

 INIT_STRUCT(&snapshot_parms);
result = get_system_snapshot(&snapshot_parms);
```

Comment: What does the documentation or the existing code samples say about how this function is to be called? Specifically, a struct with a `size` member is often supposed to be initialized by setting this member to the size of the struct as seen by the caller -- this is a common technique to support versioned structs. From simply seeing the argument as a `SNAPSHOT_PARMS*`, you cannot tell if the caller expects any data to be initialized before the call.

Comment: I've added some details above (for easier formatting), but it all looks fairly benign to my eyes - is it doing something different to the C# code?

Comment: There you go -- the C++ code indeed 1) sets the `size` member and 2) wants the function to put its data in that struct. The C# code doesn't do 1 and cannot work with 2, because the struct is only ever passed by value as an input parameter. The parameter to `GetSystemSnapshot` shouldn't be an `IntPtr`, but a `ref SNAPSHOT_PARMS`, and it should be initialized with `new SNAPSHOT_PARMS { size = Marshal.SizeOf<SNAPSHOT_PARMS>() }`.

Comment: I think `cppsharp` is more hindrance than help in this case -- I see what it's trying to do, but its wrappers don't really make things simpler, and it's imported some things it shouldn't have imported (like the copy constructor on `SNAPSHOT_PARMS`). The `__Internal` structure it's put in the class is really all you need, combined with the `GetSystemSnapshot` import.

Comment: Thank you - that helps immensely, and I'm now getting values back from the library. Please add that as an answer and I'll mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C++ declarations, this should suffice:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe struct SNAPSHOT_PARMS {
    public int size;
    public int count;
    public fixed byte serial_no[600];
}

[DllImport("res_lib", EntryPoint = "get_system_snapshot")]
static extern int GetSystemSnapshot(ref SNAPSHOT_PARMS snapshot);
```

Use as

```
var s = new SNAPSHOT_PARMS { size = Marshal.SizeOf<SNAPSHOT_PARMS>() };
int result = GetSystemSnapshot(ref s);
// check result, use s
```